# Positioning the UITableView of moreNavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I have a custom header image for my NavigationController which is 54 pixels high. 
Everything works fine until I click on "More" in my UITabBar. 
I can't read part of the text of the first line in the TableView because it clips under the header image. 
I've looked at every topic about customizing the moreNavigationController without any luck. Does anyone know how to change the position of the TableView so that it starts right after the 54 pixels of my custom header? 
[image]